# attach image to poll choice

Tags: 7, media, polls

I have a polls module that comes with drupal 7 enabled, But I need to attach an image filed to a choice, so when users add a choice to pull they get to add an image to it not to the node itself. is there a way to add this image?

Answer (score 1):

I just got [Advanced Poll](http://drupal.org/project/advpoll) with the sandbox module [Advanced Poll Field Image](http://drupal.org/sandbox/xandeadx/1871070) to do the trick!

Comment: Great looking module, Is it going to be published anytime soon?

Comment: Nope: http://drupal.org/node/1939460#comment-7359174

Answer (score 1):

We solved this task by adding a field collection to the poll content type and then mapping the field collection items to the answer options via `hook_form_after_build()`.

So when you create a poll and add three answers you then have to add three images in the field collection in the same order as the answers were added.

By that field collection approach you can also add a text field and other additional content to the poll. Maybe the frontend mapping also works via `poll-vote.tpl.php` and by grabbing the node id from the URL and then loading the node and the field collection items within.

Tried Advanced Poll as well but it seems kind of buggy and outdated.